# Is it possible to launch an Android Instant app from a Facebook post?

Tags: android, facebook

I'm sure some weeks ago I was able to do it from a firebase dynamic link and also from a meta refresh tag like this :

Is it a bug or the feature is not supported anymore ?

Comment: Hi! Have you found a solution?

Comment: you can redirect the user to the instant app from the webpage

Comment: by using this syntax 
https://developer.chrome.com/docs/multidevice/android/intents/ ,
it works also with the Facebook browser.